# Syntax error for validation rule

Tags: validation-rule, compile-error

I can not find the Syntax error. Extra ','

```
AND( 
 OR(ISPICKVAL( StageName , "1 - Prospect"), 
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "2 - Strategy/Proposal Generation"), 
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "3 - Proposal Submitted"), 
 ISPICKVAL( StageName , "4 - Negotiation") 
), 
CONTAINS($Label.Oppty_Rec_Type_Id_s, RecordTypeId), 
AND 
( 
 YEAR(CloseDate) > 1900, 
 MOD(MONTH(CloseDate), 3) = 0, 
 DAY(CloseDate) > 15 )
),
AND
( 
 ISNULL( Comments__c ) 
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks to me like you have an extra close parenthesis after

```
DAY(CloseDate) > 15 )
```

resulting in closing your outermost `AND()` early. Then the comma appears to be superfluous. You'll need to move that extra parenthesis, I think, to the end of the expression to ensure everything balances.

To simplify, you can drop your inner `AND()` functions and include their parameters inline in your outermost function call. Remember that

```
AND(A, AND(B, C))
```

is equivalent to

```
AND(A, B, C)
```

Comment: @nameishi I have a suggestion: grab a copy of Visual Studio Code and install the extension Bracket Pair Colorizer. It can help you find issues like this where parens don't match the way you think they do. Just paste your formula into the text editor and inspect it there.